# JIRA - JQL with Webook - Only trigger webhook if change was not caused by certain user

Tags: jira, jql, jqlite

We're using Slack and JIRA together and we want to create one webhook for every of our users. If any user A makes a change in user B's issues, user A should be notified via Slack. But if user A makes a change in user A's issues, user A should NOT get a notification in slack.

We tried the following JQL statement for the user "max":

```
project = "Project Name" AND assignee="max" AND NOT status changed AFTER "-2m" by "max"
```

Unfortunately it does not work.

If Max makes a change to his issues, he gets a notification in Slack, but if he changes the same issue again afterwards, he does not. It seems like the "status change by" is not set at the time the webhook is triggered, but only afterwards.
Is there some kind of field for the User who triggered the webhook? That is essentially what we need.

EDIT:

More info: We're using this Slack integration and combining it with the webhook:
https://marketplace.atlassian.com/plugins/eu.wisoft.slack.jira/cloud/overview

I created an additional "all Jira notifications"-configuration with this Slack-plugin and it works quite fine. Hence, the slack plugin does work fine, but my JQL filtering is the issue apparently.

Last try:

```
project = "Project Name" 
AND assignee="max" 
AND status changed AFTER -2m 
AND NOT status changed by "max" AFTER -2m
```

Using this from a comment, I was able to get it to work inconsistently:
A new jira-issue that I put on Todo with "max" and assignee "max", that is moved by another user to "Progress" (hence status-change), does not cause the webhook to trigger. The next time, the same user changes this issue from progress to todo or back, the webhook is triggered. It feels like at the time of the webhook call, the latest information is not available. It feels like at the time of the first change, this part fails:

```
AND status changed AFTER -2m
```

How could I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the JQL you're looking for is this:

```
project = "Project Name" 
AND assignee="max" 
AND status changed AFTER -2m 
AND NOT status changed BY "max" AFTER -2m
```

This is telling JIRA:

> Give me everything in project-name;
>
> That is owned by max;
>
> Limit it to anything where the last status change was after 2 minutes ago
>
> Further limit it so that the last status change was NOT done by max in the last 2 minutes

Comment: Thanks for the idea, but it doesn't work. With this we get no notifications at all. Neither if "max" change something, nor if the others do.

Comment: Could be that the last clause is looking at the entire history of the ticket. Try this instead for the last clause:
**AND NOT status changed by "max" AFTER -2m**

Comment: It still doesn't seem to work....though once it came through now and once it didn't. Any more ideas to make it work better?

Comment: We're closer :) Could be that your tests are conducted inside the 2minute timeframe? Also, did you test on (1) a brand new issue (2) an issue transitioned by max for the first time,  (3) an issue transitioned by max multiple times (4) an issue transitioned by not-max for the first time (5) not-max multiple times

Comment: I tested on an existing issue that was already changed by "max", multiple times. I just created a brand new user for testing and moved the issue from todo to progress - no notification. But then I did again (back and forth) and the notification came through.

Comment: The behaviour seems consistent, but weird ;)  If not-max moves an issue for the first time, max does not get a notification. But if not-max moves this issue afterwards, max does get notified.

Comment: So aside from the initial case it looks like the proposed code is working. If so, I'll update the actual answer and you can mark it as accepted

Comment: Haha, no it's not working, since the first change doesn't work ;)

Comment: Are you checking that the jql results in search match what you're seeing in slack, or only checking slack?  There could be a challenge in the web hook. Also when you say "moved" the issue, are you certain that is causing a status change? Lastly, can you also update your question with a bit more clarity on which system is triggering the web hook, what the condition /situation/context of the web hook trigger is and which system's API endpoint is being accessed?  Thx

Comment: I'm certain it causes a state change (moving from TODO to Progress and back, etc.). I've updated the question :) If you need more info....I'm happy to provide anything you need.

Comment: I marked your answer now as correct, even though it does not work. But it's not your fault ;) I asked Attlassian, the started investigating and it turned out as a bug that it does not work the way you suggested it. If you have another idea how to do this, it'd be highly appreciated, otherwise I'll have to wait until they fix it.

Comment: @keyboard Phew, I thought I was going crazy. Can you add a link to the bug?  Thx!

Comment: It's in a non-public ticket, so there's not really a link I guess. They didn't provide me with an official link to a bug tracker. The bug is exactly what we though it is: At the time when the webhook is fired, the timing of the last change are not yet written to the database / the JQL can not access the time of the even that triggered it.